# How do run a stored procedure from SQL in VBA and then paste the data into Excel?

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, stored-procedures

So I am quite new to VBA but I need to write a VBA macro which runs the stored procedure in Microsoft SQL server and then paste this data into the excel worksheet.

So far this is the code that I have, but I am not sure how to proceed? Is there sample code or a template for this particular procedure?

```
Sub Connection()   ' create the connection

loginstatus = True
login.Show
Password = login.password_input
user = login.UserName


Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim stored_procedure As String
Dim ADODBCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset



Set con = New ADODB.Connection

'provide and create connection string
 Dim connectionString As String

Dim location As String  'the server

location = "MyLocation"

connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Data Source=" & location & ";Command Timeout=0;Connection Timeout=0;Packet Size=4096; Initial Catalog=ukmc; User ID=" & user & "; Password=" & Password & ";"

'handle when it is not possible to log in
On Error GoTo ConnectionError

con.Open connectionString
loginstatus = False
Exit Sub


'errorhandl0
ConnectionError:
 MsgBox "Not possible to log in. Have you entered the correct password?"

'recordset - the data extracted
Set ADODBCmd = New ADODB.Command

End Sub
```

So i think I have created the connection, but how do I tell it which stored procedure to run and then how do i paste the data into a worksheet in my excel document?

Comment: CopyFromRecordset is the pasting to worksheet tip.   https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/563913-sql-copyfromrecordset.html

Comment: @SMeaden Ok, but how do I run the stored procedure to get the data?

Comment: that link also gives stored procedure example.

Answer (score 0):

From the [link](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/563913-sql-copyfromrecordset.html)

```
myConnection.Open
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConnection
Set myRecordSet.ActiveConnection = myConnection
myCommand.CommandText = strSQL
myCommand.CommandType = adCmdText
myCommand.Execute
myRecordSet.Open myCommand

'Paste to spreadsheet
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report").Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset
myRecordSet
```